# Django annotate Count over queryset results

Tags: python, django

Let's imagine the next model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, ...)
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type, ...)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform, ...)
    [...]
```

Users can filter by every ForeignKey__id field and the filtered queryset is used to construct a dynamic filter for the frontend with next structure:

```
"filter": {
    "categories": [
        {
            "category__id": 1,
            "category__name": "videogames",
            "total": 12
        },
        {
            "category__id": 2,
            "category__name": "funkos",
            "total": 3
        }
    ],
    "types": [
        {
            "type__id": 3,
            "type__name": "accessory",
            "total": 2
        },
        {
            "type__id": 2,
            "type__name": "console",
            "total": 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Where **total** is the number of Products associated with each category, type, etc..
The values are calculated as following:

```
categories = queryset.values('category__id', 'category__name').annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

**queryset** can also be filtered by, for example, products with a price grater than 25.00$.

Is there any way to get the **total field value** (currently **annotate(total=Count('id'))**) based on *queryset values*, not on database values?

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by `queryset values` as opposed to `database values`? If you have an already filtered queryset, then `queryset.values('category__id', 'category__name').annotate(total=Count('id'))` will already give you the counts based on that filtering.

Comment: I assume `queryset` is already a filtered query set, on which you are applying annotate method. In this case, you have to redefine the queryset.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but `queryset.values('category__id', 'category__name').annotate(total=Count('id'))` give me wrong results. Instead, `aggregate(total=Count('id'))` gives me the correct result (but then I cannot append this result to the queryset fields).